# Match on Scala Manifest

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a method that parses an json to an object. Currently I have two `def` that does exactly the same thing, except one parses `A` and the other parses `List[A]`.

This is how it looks like:

```
def parse[A <: V2Model](mf: Manifest[A]) = {
  // doing parsing
}

def parseList[A <: V2Model](mf: Manifest[List[A]]) = {
  // doing parsing of list
}
```

It is not very readable to have two of the same ´def´. The manifest is not implicit.

**Is there a way to match on Manifest?**

I have tried this without success:

```
def parse[A <: V2Model](mf: Manifest[A]) = {
  mf match {
    case _ : Manifest[List[A]] => // do list parsing
    case _ : Manifest[A] => // do object parsing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If A is subtype of V2Model, then "mf: Manifest[A]" will never be Manifest[List[A]].

Also there are no common return type between A and List[A], so it's not possible to achieve what you want.

The question is, why you want to behave differently when parsing Lists and when parsing objects? Serialization frameworks already resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This code is for a **temporary** proxy with a lof of old models that need to behave like the new (v2) model. I know its ugly, but it was super fast to develop. 
Now I'm just trying to refactor some parts of it.

Comment: You probably need something with this signature: def parse[A](json: String)(implicit mf: Manifest[A]): A (or returning Try[A], Either[ParseError, A], etc). That should work with normal objects and also lists.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general, but for this case (and still ugly):

```
if (mf.runtimeClass == classOf[List[_]]) {
  // a list manifest
} else {
  // not a list manifest
}
```